# Why does this autoclicker only click once and stop?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

With this simple auto-clicker made on the Logitech scripting area using LUA i want it to click whenever mouse button 5 is held down (forward button), but instead it clicks once and stops. this auto-clicker (same code) works perfectly fine with mouse button 3 but not 4 or 5. maybe this is a glitch with my mouse not being able to register the button being held down.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   --OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then 
      repeat 
         PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(math.random(50, 100)) 
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
   end
end
```

Comment: Mouse button 5 must have standard command ("Forward") assigned to it in LGS/GHUB.

Comment: how do i get this same auto-clicker too right click instead of left click

Comment: `PressAndReleaseMouseButton(3)`